# connect grid view to database

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I build a ASP.net project but I'm new in it ...

I got this problem :

got a textbox1 and button name = filter and grid view

there is database with too table (mark , Course )

I need when I write a sentence in textbox1 and press filter grid view connect to databse and take the data according to the textbox1 content

and by default bring every thing without filter

I make it but The grid view don't appear
there is no error

```
<table >
<tr>
<td colspan= "2" bgcolor="#4B6C9E"  >
<font color = white> Choose The Course :</font>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Course :" ></asp:Label>
   </td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan = "2" align = "center">
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Filter" />
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>

    <br />
<br />
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StdID" HeaderText="StdID" SortExpression="StdID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Mark" HeaderText="Mark" SortExpression="Mark" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseID" HeaderText="CourseID" 
                SortExpression="CourseID" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="StudentName" 
                SortExpression="StudentName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CourseName" HeaderText="CourseName" 
                SortExpression="CourseName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Year" HeaderText="Year" SortExpression="Year" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Semester" HeaderText="Semester" 
                SortExpression="Semester" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Grade" HeaderText="Grade" SortExpression="Grade" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Marks.StdID, Marks.Mark, Marks.CourseID, Marks.StudentName, Course.CourseName, Course.Year, Course.Semester, Course.Grade FROM Marks INNER JOIN Course ON Marks.CourseID = Course.ID WHERE (Course.CourseName LIKE '@name')">
        <SelectParameters>
                 <asp:ControlParameter Name="name" ControlID="TextBox1" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="%" Type="String"  />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

note: when I execute the query in database its worked perfect

please help as fast as you can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gridiview doenst show anything if there is no row coming from the datasource.
This clause is wrong "WHERE (Course.CourseName LIKE '@name'", you don't need to put @name inside string, the database will search for a course named '@name', put the parameter directly inside the SQL. 
This way:

```
 SelectCommand="SELECT Marks.StdID, Marks.Mark, Marks.CourseID, Marks.StudentName, Course.CourseName, Course.Year, Course.Semester, Course.Grade FROM Marks INNER JOIN Course ON Marks.CourseID = Course.ID WHERE (Course.CourseName LIKE @name)"
```